# re-attach to other terminal(xterm) after it stop (like -hold in xterm)

Tags: xterm, gnome-terminal, pty, terminal-emulator

I can execute program in other terminal (like xterm -e ls). and hold that xterm when the program exit. (using xterm -hold -e ls).

My question is can I re-run some program in that xterm which is hold by the -hold option.

Or can I open xterm without any program run in that. I want later manually start some program in that terminal.
like:
$xterm --"do not run shell and wait further program to run in it"
$run some program in that xterm.

Answer (score 0):

no - when you are viewing the result from

```
xterm -hold -e ls
```

the `ls` command has already exited, and xterm is only keeping the display running so that you can view the screen (and minor things such as selecting text from the screen to paste in another window).  There is nothing which you could reattach to.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pity.

Comment: I guess a real terminal is always there and can be reattach to. So should the terminal emulator.